# Change style using button and save this state

Tags: android, layout, styles, savestate

I have two color styles for my app.
I can change them using button, but i haven't got idea how I could save actually style as domestic. When I restart my app, I have other style than I choose.
Have You got idea how I can save this state? Maybe `savedInstanceState`?
Thank's for any reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about persisting the changes? You can use SharedPreferences just like that:

```
// While choosing new style
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putInt("style", styleId);
editor.commit(); // commit changes

// While retriving choosen style
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
int styleId = pref.getInt("style", null); // null is default value
setStyle(styleId); // custom method
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank You. I will try with with your solution :)